# Information saved in memory when using pending request in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I learning LINQ, and i want to use pending request, but i have this problem

```
            List<string> _strs = new List<string> { "1", "2", "1", "1", "0" };
            var selind = _strs.Select((name, ind) => new { indexname = name, index = ind }).Where(o => o.indexname == "1");
            string sind = "";
            foreach (var item in selind)
                sind += item.index.ToString() + " ";
            //i get 0 2 3 
            _strs.Add("2");
            _strs.Add("1");
            sind = "";
            foreach (var item in selind)
                sind += item.index.ToString() + " ";
            //Good, i get 0 2 3 6
            _strs = new List<string>() { "1" };
            sind = "";
            foreach (var item in selind)
                sind += item.index.ToString() + " ";
            //Why i get again 0 2 3 6
```

Ok i understand why, but I wolud like to know two things:

- How should i clear memory?

  selind = null;
  Or you can tell me more nice way?
- For work with selind after total rebuild of _strs i find two way

  ```
          _strs.Clear();
          _strs.Add();
  ```

or call again

```
selind = _strs.Select((name, ind) => new { indexname = name, index = ind }).Where(o => o.indexname == "1");
```

Can you advice me another way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query:

```
_strs.Select((name, ind) => new { indexname = name, index = ind }).Where(o => o.indexname == "1");
```

Is tied to a particular list reference in memory (whatever `_strs` is at that time), not to a particular variable name. They are not the same thing. When you do this:

```
_strs = new List<string>() { "1" };
```

You're not clearing the memory reference of where `_strs` originally pointed. You are instead having that variable name point to a new memory location. Whereas `_strs.Clear()` does clear the original list.

The best solution for your problem is to wrap the LINQ query in a function that accepts a list, so you can call it again on new lists without typing it again. Alternatively, depending on your use case, just call `.Clear()` when you need to start again.

(in case this wasn't clear, `_strs = null` does nothing to the list that `_strs` used to point to, it just makes that particular variable name invalid)

Comment: Thank you but i wolud like to use pending request, so i want to make 'selind' in global, can you give some advice about it? ('_strs' is just example, i use some other global list with object)

Comment: As you suggest, you can run `Clear` on it and reuse the same list. Then the single LINQ query will continuously operate against the same underlying list. There is no other way to 'repoint' the query to a new list without reissuing the LINQ commands.